# how to pass a variable to isodate in python?

Tags: python, string, youtube-api, isodate

I'm getting the duration value from youtube's v3 api.

I then want to pass that value to isodate function that turns the iso format
into seconds.

```
       ytContentDetails = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=%s&key=%s"%(ytID, ytAPIkey)).json()
       ytDUR = ytContentDetails['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration']
       print ytDUR
       ytTime = isodate.parse_duration('%f') ytDUR
```

But I keep getting an error.

```
       ytTime = isodate.parse_duration('%r')% ytDUR
       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/isodate/isoduration.py", line 99, in parse_duration
       raise ISO8601Error("Unable to parse duration string %r" % datestring)
       ISO8601Error: Unable to parse duration string '%f'
```

Where am I going wrong?

I've tried changing %f to different conversions, to no avail.

I think this is a clue...

```
       parse_duration:
       parses an ISO 8601 duration string into a timedelta or Duration object.
```

the ytDUR value outputs something like ....

```
       PT6M19S
```

Comment: For those of us without Youtube API access, can you give the output of `type(ytDUR), str(ytDUR)`?

Comment: ok check edit...it basically outputs a iso8601 string

Comment: Okay. So that string's not going to work with `%f`, which is for floats. Why not just `ytTime = isodate.parse_duration(ytDUR)`? It worked for me, i.e. `isodate.parse_duration('PT6M19S')`.

Comment: K.i.S.S... Thanks! make it a answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `ytTime = isodate.parse_duration(ytDUR)`? It worked for me, i.e. `isodate.parse_duration('PT6M19S')`.